# Regex routing with Express, optional pattern matching doesn't seem to work?

Tags: express

I'm using a route like this:

```
app.get( '/(aaa(?:&bbb)*)'
```

which should match

```
/aaa
/aaa&bbb
/aaa&bbb&bbb&bbb
```

but it's only matching

```
/aaabbb
```

I've removed the repeating modifier so it's only

```
app.get( '/(aaa(?:&bbb))'
```

but it's still only matching `aaa&bbb` and not matching `aaa`

I've been trying to google this but have been unable to find anyone else with the same problem.

Should I be escaping it someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the `/`

```
'\/(aaa(?:&bbb)*)
```

I have tested this and have confirmed that it matches

```
/aaa
/aaa&bbb
/aaa&bbb&bbb&bbb
```